# Can I add to grammar word that can not be applied in lexer rule?

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer

I have grammar like:

```
assignment: NAME ':=' (value | operation | boolean_value);
NAME: [a-zA-Z]+;
```

And I want to program `true := 4` was wrong but it isn't.

I want in grammar say that word `true` cant be applied as `NAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Then have it defined as a keyword:

```
assignment: NAME ':=' (value | operation | boolean_value);

TRUE : 'true'; 
NAME : [a-zA-Z]+;
```

or perform the semantic check in [a listener or visitor](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md).

Comment: Super, it helps me with keywords ```true``` and ```false```. But I have keyword ```skip``` too.

```
command: assignment | if_condition | while_loop | comparison | operation | SKIP_RULE;
assignment: NAME ':=' (value | operation | boolean_value);

TRUE: 'true';
FALSE: 'false';
SKIP_RULE: 'skip';
```

If I enter command: ```skip := 6```. ANTLR finds keyword ```skip``` and ignores the rest of command. I want that command like ```skip := 6``` was assignment type not skip. Is there some solution without semantic check?

Comment: Your comment contains more information than your original question. Please edit your question and add this info to it instead.